# Directly send user to sign up page with firebase ui

Tags: firebase, firebase-authentication, firebaseui

I'm using firebase ui for a project and they only seem to offer sign-in ui by default until a new user tries signing in with a email that hasn't been registered before. Is it possibly to show a sign up button right off the bat?

firebase ui repo - https://github.com/firebase/firebaseui-web#known-issues